# Parse/separate a file into different data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a file in the following format:

```
$ cat file
Latitude Longitude 123.4 1234.5
1 2 34.4 
34.2 34 54
78 999 999 999
999 999 999 999
Latitude Longitude 12.4 14.5
78 999 999 999
999 999 999 999
1 2 34.4 
34.2 34 54
```

I want to split this file into two separate data frames (in R preferably) where dataframe 1 has:

```
Latitude Longitude 123.4 1234.5
1 2 34.4 
34.2 34 54
78 999-999-999
999-999-999-999
```

and data frame 2 has :

```
Latitude Longitude 12.4 14.5
78 999-999-999
999-999-999-999
1 2 34.4 
34.2 34 54
```

I tried using linux (instead of using functions in R like subset and regexpr) such as awk and sed but was not able to parse it out and put the desired out in separate files.

The following are actually headers :
1) Latitude Longitude 12.4 14.5
2) Latitude Longitude 123.4 1234.5

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: You have different numbers of variables for each row of your output (i.e. 4, 3, 4, 2, 1). How do you wish this to be addressed? Also, is the Latitude / Longitude meant to be a header rather than data?

Comment: I have the same questions as @thelatemail. Without knowing those answers, I would create an indicator for "Latitude" (probably using `grep`) and then use `split`.

Comment: I would find out which row number the second header starts at then use head (or tail) in a terminal to output to your new file.